# How To add refrence to desktop application in C#.NET

Tags: c#, dll, reference, desktop-application

I want to add a dll file to my desktop application but I get error How can I fix it
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUZ8h.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the dll code?

Comment: I have dll file.noCode I have. If you want to check I can Email you. I have Downloaded It from it's website

Comment: MR Ehsan Akbar.Can you Help Me????

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error image it looks like you are trying to reference a 64Bit DLL. Is your project set to Any CPU ? And was this the only DLL available in their SDK?

Comment: Yes I am trying 64bit DLL. And My Project Is set to Any CPU .also I have 32bit

Comment: MR Ehsan Akbar Could you become successful?